# Python -- Read and compare rows and columns

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, csv

```
0,1,foo
0,0,foo
0,1,foo
1,1,foobar
1,1,foobar
0,1,test
1,1,foobarbar
```

about 10,000 entries.

Let that be the csv file.

I want to know how many '0's' from the first column concern with Foo. and the number of '1's' and '0's' concern with foo in the second column separately.

Do I read the previous line in that file and check? Is there way to work with it using List comprehension? How do I maintain a counter there?

Expected output:

```
Foo
Coloumn1 : 
No. of 0's = 3
no. of 1's = 0
column 2:
no. of 1's =2
no. of 0's =1
```

Comment: What does "concern with Foo" mean?  Contains "foo" (case-insensitively) as a substring?  Starts with "foo"?  To be concrete: what do you want to happen with `barfoo`?

Comment: Do you *only* care about foo? or do you want this data for other all unique third-column values?

Comment: Please give the expected output for the example input given in the question.

Comment: @Mhlester: I do care about other columsn

Comment: @SunnyNanda: The expected output is
`Foo
Coloumn1 : 
No. of 0's = 3
no. of 1's = 0
column 2:
no. of 1's =2
no. of 0's =1

Comment: @pistal, sorry I meant do you care about the non-foo *rows*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter
import csv

with open('myfile.csv', 'rb') as inf:
    incsv = csv.reader(inf)
    col1, col2 = defaultdict(Counter), defaultdict(Counter)
    for c1,c2,label in incsv:
        col1[label][c1] += 1
        col2[label][c2] += 1

labels = sorted(col1)
for lbl in labels:
    print('{}:'.format(lbl))
    print('Column1:')
    for entry in ['0', '1']:
        print("No. of {}'s = {}".format(entry, col1[lbl][entry]))
    print('Column2:')
    for entry in ['0', '1']:
        print("No. of {}'s = {}".format(entry, col2[lbl][entry]))
```

returns

```
foo:
Column1:
No. of 0's = 3
No. of 1's = 0
Column2:
No. of 0's = 1
No. of 1's = 2
foobar:
Column1:
No. of 0's = 0
No. of 1's = 2
Column2:
No. of 0's = 0
No. of 1's = 2
foobarbar:
Column1:
No. of 0's = 0
No. of 1's = 1
Column2:
No. of 0's = 0
No. of 1's = 1
test:
Column1:
No. of 0's = 1
No. of 1's = 0
Column2:
No. of 0's = 0
No. of 1's = 1
```

Comment: The foo's are not necessarily in a continous fashion.. so, foo can occur recurringly

Comment: I also get this error: _csv.Error: line contains NULL byte

Answer (score 1):

### Building the data

```
datastring = """0,1,foo
0,0,foo
0,1,foo
1,1,foobar
1,1,foobar
0,1,test
1,1,foobarbar"""

def count_data(datastring):
    datadict = {}
    for line in datastring.split('\n'):
        col1, col2, col3 = line.split(',')
        for i, colval in enumerate((col1, col2)): # doing it this way in case there are more cols
            datadict.setdefault(col3, {}).setdefault(colval, [0, 0])[i] += 1
    return datadict
datadict = count_data(datastring)
```

Outputs:

```
{'test': {'1': [0, 1], '0': [1, 0]}, 'foobar': {'1': [2, 2]}, 'foo': {'1': [0, 2], '0': [3, 1]}, 'foobarbar': {'1': [1, 1]}}
```

### Displaying the data

```
def print_data(datadict):
    for key in datadict:
        print key
        for i, col in enumerate(datadict[key]):
            print 'Column', i+1, ':'
            colvalues = datadict[key][col]
            for value in (0, 1):
                print "Number of {0}'s:".format(value), colvalues[value]
```

### Output

```
test
Column 1 :
Number of 0's: 0
Number of 1's: 1
Column 2 :
Number of 0's: 1
Number of 1's: 0
foobar
Column 1 :
Number of 0's: 2
Number of 1's: 2
foo
Column 1 :
Number of 0's: 0
Number of 1's: 2
Column 2 :
Number of 0's: 3
Number of 1's: 1
foobarbar
Column 1 :
Number of 0's: 1
Number of 1's: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code's list comprehension creates a list that includes every line in the file where the last column's string is `'foo'` `and` the current `column`'s string is the number you're looking for. Printing the length of that list will give you the number of occurrences:

**file.txt:**

```
0,1,foo
0,0,foo
0,1,foo
1,1,foobar
1,1,foobar
0,1,test
1,1,foobarbar
```

**Code:**

```
search_string = 'foo\n'
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = list(f)
    for column in [0, 1]: # Let's count columns from 0
        print "Column %d: " % (column)
        for number in ['0', '1']: # Strings for .csv file
            print "Number of %s's = " % (number),
            print len([line for line in lines if
                       (line.split(',')[-1] == search_string and
                       line.split(',')[column] == number)])
```

**Output:**

```
Column 0: 
Number of 0's =  3
Number of 1's =  0
Column 1: 
Number of 0's =  1
Number of 1's =  2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
file = "a.csv"
search = "foo"
lines = open(file).readlines()
(firstcol_zero, firstcol_one, secondcol_zero, secondcol_one) = (0, 0 ,0 ,0 )
for line in lines:
    line = line.strip()
    if not line : continue
    split = line.split(',')
    if not split[2] == search: continue
    if (int(split[0]) == 0):    firstcol_zero += 1
    elif (int (split[0]) == 1): firstcol_one += 1
    if (int(split[1]) == 0):    secondcol_zero += 1
    elif (int (split[1]) == 1): secondcol_one += 1

print firstcol_zero
print firstcol_one
print secondcol_zero
print secondcol_one
```